# What does "$" symbol mean in Lua?

Tags: lua

I wonder how the dollar symbol `$` is used in Lua.

Is it reserved for anything?

If so, I would appreciate an example of it.

Comment: The answer to this question can be found in the Lua documentation, even an example is provided there.

Comment: `$` is the same as `C:\>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a part of the language. Instead, it's used to denote that "anything after this dollar sign should be executed in a shell."

E.g., you might see:

```
$ python  
$ from pywinauto.application import Application
```

So you would instead type:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
```

Typically, it's used to indicate what you provide to your shell's prompt and what the output is.